# How can I break the infinite loop or working the code in r?

Tags: r

I want to build the function with three statement('for', 'while', and 'rep').

So, I write the code below.

```
 f <- function(x){
   y <- 1
    for(i in 1:x){
      while(((1:x)[i]) < x){
        y<-rep(y*((1:x)[i]))
     }
   }
    print(y)
 }
```

I try the working the code.

But, no error message and just 'stop'sign in console.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck in the while loop, thats why `i` never increases (the for loop only runs once) which means that `(1:x)[i]` will always be 1. 
This function actually works, but only for the user input `x < 2`. To be more precise only for `x = 0`.

Let us know what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise we won`t be able to help you, since it's actually working (although very limited).

**Note** that `rep()`with just **one** argument will always return the number just once.

Also, since your question is a little unclear: If you want to stop the code execution, simply click on the `stop` sign.